# Wicket: form model object filled with null

Tags: java, forms, wicket

It is probably a what-am-I-missing question, but I have this form in html !

```
<form wicket:id="expiration">
<input type="text" wicket:id="field"/>
    <span class="button" wicket:id="expirationsubmit">Submit</span>
</form>
```

which, on submit, fills the form's model object with null whatever I enter in the field.

```
final Form expirationForm = new Form("expiration");
OneIntContext expirationContext = new OneIntContext("0");
expirationForm.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(expirationContext));
expirationForm.add(new TextField("field"));
expirationForm.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("expirationsubmit") {
    @Override
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        OneIntContext context = (OneIntContext) expirationForm.getModelObject();
        context.getField().toString();//this throws a NullPointerException
        //validations and actions
    }
}
```

OneIntContext contrains only one field called "field" (+ getter/setter/constructor) and I tried with a Stringa and an Integer, nothing seems to fit, I only get null everytime.

Does anyone have any sort of idea ?

Thank you all

A.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Show us OneIntContext.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a definite answer without the answer to SvenMeier's question above. Also, it would be good to know what returned null in the line where you got your NullPointerException.

However, in many of my onSubmit() methods, I use code of the following form to get at the object of my compound property loadable detachable models:

```
Form frm = getForm();    // You might want to try using the form parameter instead
CompoundPropertyModel cpmModel = (CompoundPropertyModel)frm.getModel();
PageStatementSummaryModel pmModel =
 (PageStatementSummaryModel)cpmModel.getChainedModel();
PageStatementSummaryData pdData = pmModel.getObject();
```